# Offering cash prizes?

Tags: discussion

TCS SE contain many old questions without any answer. I think it is a good idea to allow offering cash-prizes for those questions.

Should we allow offering cash prizes for solving problems without any answer?

EDIT: What is the official StackExchange policy on offering cash prizes?

Comment: Who provides the cash? How will the cash be paid? What about taxes?

Comment: Anyone interested in the answer can provide the cash. Personally, I have couple of questions that I love to offer cash prizes. Payments could be made by checks or wire transfer. Here, we do not have taxes ;)

Comment: way cool idea!! =) but unlikely to "fly" on stackexchange. another simple option is to offer rewards on a web page & cite the questions via urls. it would also be neat if math/cs foundations [there are several] offered small rewards for open problems for incremental progress, outside of the "gamechanger" level problems like [claymath.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems)

Comment: see also mathoverflow [open problems with monetary awards](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66084/open-problems-with-monetary-rewards) and also note Erdos offered many awards although it is difficult to find a published list. Knuth also offered prizes.

Comment: There has been long discussion about this on meta.MO. If someone want to do so on say his own website they can do so but based MO meta discussions I think it is not a good idea to provide cash prized on cstheory.

Comment: note, esp if the problems are at a medium level of difficulty & not extremely difficult (which would tend to discourage attempts), this also fits in with [site promotion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/377/site-promotion-the-next-phase)